# use of undeclared identifier and unused variable warning of same variable

Tags: c++, variables

I'm making a c++ program and in it I have the section

```
Point originzarm = normalizevector(camera.origin.x, camera.origin.y, camera.origin.z);
if (camera.origin.x == 0 and camera.origin.y == 0) {
    Point originxarm(1,0,0);
}
else{
    Point originxarm = normalizevector(camera.origin.y, -camera.origin.x, 0);
}
Point originyarm = crossproduct(originxarm.x, originxarm.y, originxarm.z, originzarm.x, originzarm.y, originzarm.z);
```

the functions cross product and normalize vector return points.
in the else section there's a warning about unused variable originxarm. but when i try to use originxarm while defining originyarm it says use of undeclared identifier originxarm. How could I make originxarm visible after the if else statement and set it within the curly brackets?

PS I asked this a long time ago when I was just beginning to understand C++.

Comment: the scope of the variable originxarm is not available after the else block. Declare the variable before the if block and intialize it in else block.

Comment: I think you need a good C++ book. For now you can read up on [scopes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope).

Comment: A variable exists only in the nearest scope to its definition (curly braces). There is no `originxarm` after the `if/else` statement. This is unlike a language like python, which has closures.

Comment: then how do i use it. also camera.origin.x and camera.origin.y are equals to 0 so why is it going to the else block

Comment: How does "it goes to the else block"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the lifetime scope of your variable `originxarm`. You declare the first that only lives as long as your if-clause is no closed and a second on that lives as long as the corresponding else is not closed. But after the if-else-clause `originxarm` is not known to your program. Therefore you'll get the "undeclared identifier" error.

Neither the if-clause is using your variable inside it nor your else-clause is, therefore you get the "unused variable" warnings.

You have to modify your code:

```
Point originxarm;
Point originzarm = normalizevector(camera.origin.x, camera.origin.y, camera.origin.z);
if (camera.origin.x == 0 and camera.origin.y == 0) {
    originxarm = Point(1,0,0);
}
else{
    originxarm = normalizevector(camera.origin.y, -camera.origin.x, 0);
}
Point originyarm = crossproduct(originxarm.x, originxarm.y, originxarm.z, originzarm.x, originzarm.y, originzarm.z);
```

Comment: isn't this exactly what i have alrady never mind i see thanks so much

Comment: @BenBeazley _"isn't this exactly what i have alrady"_ No it isn't, take a closer look.

Comment: @BenBeazley The difference is, that I declared `originxarm` ouside the if-else-clause.

Answer (score 2):

`originxarm` is not used in either of the if branches. Their definition is local to the scope that is introduced by curly braces. This is correct and a basic concept of the language.

Comment: i see but how can i define those. preferably without using new